# Continuous function defined on compact set is uniformly continuous

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Here's what I'm trying to prove:

Let $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact set. If $f: K \to \mathbb{R}^p$ is a continuous map, then $f$ is uniformly continuous.

---

Proof Attempt:

Let $v(x)$ denote the norm of $x$. $v_1$ will denote the norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $v_2$ will denote the norm on $\mathbb{R}^p$.

Suppose that $f$ is not uniformly continuous. Then:

$$\exists \epsilon > 0: \forall \delta > 0: \exists x,y \in K: v_1(x-y) < \delta \land v_2(f(x)-f(y)) \geq \epsilon$$

Construct two sequences $(x^{(k)})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(y^{(k)})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that:

$$\forall k \in \mathbb{N}: v_1(x^{(k)}-y^{(k)}) < \frac{1}{k} \land v_2(f(x^{(k)})-f(y^{(k)})) \geq \epsilon$$

The compactness of $K$ guarantees the existence of two subsequences $(x^{(k_m)})_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(y^{(k_m)})_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ with limits $x$ and $y$. By the definition of the two sequences formed earlier, we can see that $x = y$ (using the Squeeze Theorem, for example).

By the continuity of $f$, it follows that:

$$\lim_{m \to \infty} [f(x^{(k_m)})-f(y^{(k_m)})] = f(x)-f(y) = 0$$

which is impossible because the above would guarantee that the norm of $f(x^{(k_m)})-f(y^{(k_m)})$ would be less than the $\epsilon$ given above for large enough $m$. $\Box$

Does the proof above work? If it doesn't, then why? How can I fix it?

**Edit:**

For that statement in the middle, I can justify it properly. Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and suppose that $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are sequences with limits $x$ and $y$ respectively. Then, $d(x_n,y_n) \to d(x,y)$.

We have, by the triangle inequality:

$$d(x_n,y_n) \leq d(x_n,x)+d(x,y)+d(y,y_n)$$

$$d(x,y) \leq d(x,x_n)+d(x_n,y_n)+d(y_n,y)$$

So, both inequalities above give us:

$$d(x,y)-d(x,x_n)-d(y,y_n) \leq d(x_n,y_n) \leq d(x_n,x)+d(x,y)+d(y,y_n)$$

Since $d(x_n,x) \to 0$ and $d(y,y_n) \to 0$, it follows that $d(x_n,y_n) \to d(x,y)$ and this is exactly what I used in the proof above.

Comment: The proof looks good to me

Comment: Noice, thank you very much :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting as an answer because I need more reputation to comment.. Anyway, I did'nt see nothing wrong except for the part: "Construct two sequences $(^{()})$ and $(^{()})$ such that:

$$_1(^{()}−^{()})<\frac{1}{k}$$

and:

$$v_2(f(x^{(k)})-f(y^{(k)})) \geq \epsilon$$

Thats dont break the hypothesis of continuity?

Comment: I don't think it breaks the hypothesis of continuity? At least, I don't see how it immediately breaks it. Also, I just edited your answer very slightly so that your math stuff got rendered properly haha

Comment: Thank you for the edit. My calculations don't show right the way the fail of continuity that i said, so i guess your proof is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much :D

Answer (score -1):

(I too lack reputation xD) Regarding the statement $x^{k_n}\to x$ and $y^{k_n}\to y$ having the same limit:

By the Squeeze theorem and from the definition of the norm $v_1(u-v)\geq 0$

$$0\leq v_1\left(x^{k_n}-y^{k_n}\right)<\dfrac{1}{k}$$

For $k\to \infty$ we have $\dfrac{1}{k}\to 0$ and thus in the limit $y=x$, as $0\leq v_1(x-y)\leq 0$